# ReportViewer Export To Excel- Merge cells

Tags: excel, reportviewer

Any idea how can i force the merge of excel cells when exporting a rdlc report to excel?

Primary KEY  |VALUES|

---

PK1...............|val1.....|
.....................|val2......|
.....................|val3......|

---

PK2          |..... |
.....................

i want that on first column(Primary key column) in the exported excel, the cells will be merged for each Primary Key

Thanks in advance
ps: sorry for that dots, didn't know how to force blanks to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

The width of the PK1 column must be equal to the width of the PK2 column + the 2nd column in the report designer.